# How to configure httpd for multiple websites each binded to a different port

Tags: apache-httpd

I am running httpd version 2.4.6 (on CentOS 7) that is hosting 2 sites, zabbix web client and an internal site that i will refer as "intra_site".
Until now, both of them used to run on port 80.
Now, we want to run each site on a different port.
I have added an additional "listen" line to the httpd conf file (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) so now i have 2 listen lines as follows:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8081
```

In Addition i have edited the "custom httpd intra_site configuration file" (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/intra_site.conf`) as follows:

```
Alias /intra_site /var/www/intra_site

<VirtualHost *:8081>

 ServerName intra_site
 ServerAlias intra_site
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting the httpd (systemctl restart httpd) **i can access to both sites from both ports, but how can i restrict that the zabbix web client will be accessible only from port 80 and "intra_site" will be accessible only from port 8081?**

I saw that someone recommended to add the following line to the virtual host:     `NameVirtualHost *:8081` as follows:

```
Alias /intra_site /var/www/intra_site
NameVirtualHost *:8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>

 ServerName intra_site
 ServerAlias intra_site
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately it did not work.

what am i missing?